# Return query results to a listbox

Tags: c#, winforms, linq

I have a class, `ExpenseItem` and a list based off that class.

I'm currently designing a form that has a combo box that would allow me to select a particular type of `ExpenseItem` Trip, and show all results in a listbox.

Form Code (`tripSelect` is the combo box and `listExpenses` is the list box):

```
    private void LoadExpenseList()
    {
        tripSelect.Items.Clear();
        var dateSorted =
            from e in roster
            group e by e.Trip into tripGroup
            select new { Trip = tripGroup.Key };
        foreach (var e in dateSorted)
            tripSelect.Items.Add(e.Trip);
    }

    private void LoadExpenseDetail()
    {
        listExpenses.Items.Clear();
        var dateSorted =
            from e in roster
            orderby e.Trip
            select e;
        foreach (var e in dateSorted) ;
    }

    private void ExpenseRecorderForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void tripSelect_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        selectedExpense = (ExpenseItem)roster.ToFind((string)tripSelect.SelectedItem);
        listExpenses.Items.Add(selectedExpense);
    }


    private void listExpenses_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tripTextBox.Text = selectedExpense.Trip;
        tripTextBox.Enabled = false;
        descriptionTextBox.Text = selectedExpense.Description;
        amountTextBox.Text = selectedExpense.Amount.ToString();
        paymentMethodTextBox.Text = selectedExpense.PaymentMethod;
        dateExpenseTimePicker.Value = selectedExpense.Date;
        dateExpenseTimePicker.Enabled = true;
        noteTextBox.Text = selectedExpense.Note;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can't code something like myVariable.Where(); since it's not IEnumerable

I don't really understand by what you mean with this.

As for the error, it says you can't cast from the `IEnumerable` to `ExpenseItem`. You have to apply it like you final example like so and return the item rather than `IEnumerable`. I would just skip the `Where` clause and go straight into using `FirstOrDefault`

```
public ExpenseItem ToFind(string trip)
{
    return this.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Trip == trip);
}
```

I presume `this` is a custom made collection otherwise the Linq extensions won't work on `this`

EDIT

If you really want this..

```
public IEnumerable<ExpenseItem> ToFind(string trip)
{
    return this.Where(e => e.Trip == trip);
}
```

Then you will need to deal with the list from the caller.

```
private void tripSelect_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IEnumerable<ExpenseItem> selectedExpenses = roster.ToFind((string)tripSelect.SelectedItem);
    foreach(ExpenseItem item in selectedExpenses)
        listExpenses.Items.Add(item);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That still only retrieves the first value, though (due to the FirstOrDefault()). 

Where doesn't work since, like you said, I can't cast from IEnumerable.

Comment: So what are you trying to achieve. The code that uses it tries to cast it to `ExpenseItem` so I presume it wants a single value. What purpose is there in returning a list unless you want multiple matches.

Comment: I do want multiple values. The form allows me to select a type of trip, then display all associated line items and edit them.

Comment: Thanks! Now my only issue is getting the records that display in the list box to cast to the text boxes. I get an error, now. Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 

I'll have to figure out a way to pass it.

Comment: I recommend post another question... but as a guess you need to bind a property on the ExpenseItem to that of the Textbox.Text property

Comment: Thanks! I've been messing around with it a bit. Here's where I'm at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10290983/cast-string-from-a-list-box-to-separate-text-fields

Answer (score 0):

If you will use this:

```
public IEnumerable<ExpenseItem> ToFind(string trip)
{
    return this.Where(e => e.Trip == trip);
}
```

You need to use this, note the FirstOrDefault:

```
selectedExpense = roster
      .ToFind((string)tripSelect.SelectedItem)
      .FirstOrDefault();
```

Your selectedExpense is not an IEnumerable:

```
private ExpenseItem selectedExpense;
```

---

By good design, if the finder matches exactly only one record, e.g. by primary key

```
public ExpenseItem ToFind(string expenseId)
{
    return this.FirstOrDefault(e => e.ExpenseId == expenseId);
}
```

,use FirstOrDefault, and then, you can it simply use the finder method like this:

```
selectedExpense = roster.ToFind(idHere);
```