# Cast string from a list box to separate text fields

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm building a program that would allow me to pull data from by selecting it from a group of Trips, and populate all found items as part of that Trip into a listbox. When I select an item from the listbox, I want it to populate a series of textboxes that allow me to edit each field.

Here's where my problem code lies within the Form (tripChoose is the combo box and listExpenses is the list box):

```
private void tripChoose_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IEnumerable<TripExpense> selectedExpenses = roster.ToFind((string)tripChoose.SelectedItem);
    foreach (TripExpense item in selectedExpenses)
        listExpenses.Items.Add(item);
}

private void listExpenses_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    specificExpenses = (TripExpense)roster.TripFind((string)listExpenses.SelectedItem);
    tripTextBox.Text = specificExpenses.Trip;
    tripTextBox.Enabled = false;
    descriptionTextBox.Text = specificExpenses.Description;
    amountTextBox.Text = specificExpenses.Amount.ToString();
    paymentMethodTextBox.Text = specificExpenses.PaymentMethod;
    dateExpenseTimePicker.Value = specificExpenses.Date;
    dateExpenseTimePicker.Enabled = true;
    noteTextBox.Text = specificExpenses.Note;
}
```

The JIT debugger lets me know that I implicitly convert an object to a string

I've tried using a ToString method like this:

```
private void tripChoose_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IEnumerable<TripExpense> selectedExpenses = roster.ToFind((string)tripChoose.SelectedItem);
    foreach (TripExpense item in selectedExpenses)
    listExpenses.Items.Add(item.ToString());
}
```

I think I'm on the right track there, as I get an error telling me that the object reference is not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue is the implementation of the `ToString()` method in `TripExpense`. When you use the string out of that and feed it into the `FindTrip` it cannot find it anymore.

What you can do instead is to have your original setting of the combo items and modify the `SelectedIndexChanged` instead

```
private void tripChoose_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IEnumerable<TripExpense> selectedExpenses = roster.ToFind((string)tripChoose.SelectedItem);
    foreach (TripExpense item in selectedExpenses)
        listExpenses.Items.Add(item);
}

private void listExpenses_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    specificExpenses = (TripExpense)listExpenses.SelectedItem;
    ... 
}
```

This way the ComboBox text will still grab the `ToString()` of the `TripExpense` object but you will still be able to get the actual object from the `SelectedItem` to play with rather than trying to requery for the object.